# Git User Commit Counts

Tags: git, tfs

We use TFS 2013 and have in the neighborhood of 90 individual repositories with 40 developers moving in and out of those repos regularly.

I'd like to produce some stats about the number of commits per user in a given time frame across all of the projects.  Is it possible to do this?  Are there any open source projects that can do it?  How about using some of the TFS libraries?  I'd sure like to avoid having to checkout each of the repos to get the info.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extract this information directly from the TFS server instead of pulling down each repository one at a time, you can. To do it though you'll need to query the TFS database directly, and you could easily write an SSRS report to make this information easy to consume.

Here's a query you can use to get started. This will show all commits across all repositories.

```
use [Tfs_DefaultCollection]

select r.Name, u.FullName, m.CommitTime, m.Comment 
from dbo.tbl_GitCommitMetadata m
left join dbo.tbl_GitCommit c on c.InternalCommitId = m.InternalCommitId
left join dbo.tbl_GitRepository r on r.InternalRepositoryId = c.InternalRepositoryId
left join dbo.tbl_GitCommitUser u on u.InternalId = m.CommitterId and u.PartitionId = m.PartitionId
order by r.Name, u.FullName, m.CommitTime
```

For reference, I have a little more information on [how TFS stores git repositories](http://www.richard-banks.org/2014/02/tfs-internals-how-does-tfs-store-git.html) on my blog.

Answer (score 1):

You can get list of users that did some changes in the repository after given date using the following command:

```
git log --branches --remotes --after 2014-11-13 --format='%aN' | sort -u
```

If you have list of users. You can get stats for given user by using command

```
git log --shortstat --branches --remotes --author="John Doe" --after 2014-11-01
```

I created a simple ruby script that will generate statistics for all users that did some changes in the repository in given period of time:

```
https://gist.github.com/kallak/1b9be6c7c7f5283b557f
```

Run the script from the git repository folder.

To get list of users and summary of changes they made between 2014-11-01 and 2014-11-13

```
git_stats.rb -a 2014-11-01 -b 2014-11-13
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [GitStats](https://github.com/tomgi/git_stats).

> GitStats is a git repository statistics generator. It browses the repository and outputs html page with statistics.

Comment: Does this require me to clone each repo that I want to get data from?

Comment: Nop. You must type `git_stats generate` on repository path. That's all.

Comment: @jeherran I think it does require a local clone.